# SonarQube rule "Methods returns should not be invariant" with catch block

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using latest SonarQube server 9.4 and it constantly reports "Refactor this method to not always return the same value." - java:S3516 in piece of code like this:

```
        try
        {
            FileUtils.moveFile(dcomExportFile, destination);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Logger.error(this, "Could not move file {} to {}, future job runs might fail as well",
                            dcomExportFile.getAbsolutePath(), destination.getAbsolutePath());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Which is very strange because method FileUtils.moveFile can throw IOException and in this case method returns false.

Any idea?

Thx!

Comment: Returning a boolean value to represent whether a method executed successfully or not is kind of an outdated pattern. Usually in this case you would just have your method `throw IOException` and each caller can than catch that exception and handle it how he wants to, instead of checking a boolean return value.

Comment: Maybe because you ignore the return value of `moveFile` ? But can't tell for sure, since I don't know which `FileUtils` you are using.

Comment: We are using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils which does not have return - void

Comment: What is strange is that SonarLint correctly does not display this issue. And when I change all to e.g. 'return true;' only then SonarLint reports it.

Answer (score 2):

I would move the `return false` statement to outside and after the catch (where return true is now). And move the `return true` to immediately follow the Fileutils call in the try block, like this:

```
    try
    {
        FileUtils.moveFile(dcomExportFile, destination);
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Logger.error(this, "Could not move file {} to {}, future job runs might fail as well",
                        dcomExportFile.getAbsolutePath(), destination.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return false;
```

It's confusing and arguably bad style to return from within a catch block anyway.

I'm not sure that in this case not letting the exception be thrown is a great idea because this seems like the sort of error I would want to bubble up, where having a return value lets it get lost too easily. Maybe it's not so bad if logging the error is the only thing the code does to handle this.

Comment: I suspect this may trigger the same SonarQube message, for the same reason as before. In which case, I would have a boolean called `success` and set it in the try & catch blocks and return that at the end.

Comment: @k314159: yeah I'm not sure either. but don't see how having a variable helps. I do think this is worth a shot, a codebase I worked on before had this pattern and I don't think sonar complained (or maybe this rule is too recent?) maybe this is part of sonar having issues with methods that have multiple return statements, I have seen it totally fail to count cyclomatic complexity for that case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may not be good idea to just catch & log exception & return `false`. You might need to throw exception back to caller of your method.

Good example which comes in my mind is [list.add(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) where if operation is success it returns `true` but in case of any failure it throws exceptions to caller instead of returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - scanning with correct sonar.java.libraries path resolves this issue.